# Run time Error '6':Visual Basic

Tags: vb6

I am using Visual Basic 6
I have the following code structure:
FUNCNINFO is a structure

```
Public funcTable() As FUNCNINFO
-----
------
ReDim Preserve funcTable(0 To upsize + ns)
```

When the value of (upsize + ns) is exceeding 32766,it is giving the runtime overflow error '6'
Do you have any idea of the cause and the solution?

Comment: Are `upsize` and `ns` ints or longs? If you're lucky this is just the 16-bit int limit (though that's usually 32767) but I wouldn't be surprised if this was an array size limit. Do you really need your funcTable that large?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VB6's `Integer` type is 16 bits so cannot store a value > 32767, its `Long` that's the 32 bit integer type so the following will work;

```
Dim upsize As Long
Dim ns As Long

upsize = 32766
ns = 12345

ReDim Preserve funcTable(0& To upsize + ns)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks..
Please note that indvidual value of upsize and ns is not exceeding size of integer,it is there combination which is exceeding.

Comment: nor are they in my example, if they were both declared as integer (or not declared at all) then a error 6 overflow is thrown

Comment: Hi Rup,
Yes this is array size limit in real scenario.

Comment: @Pradeep I think Alex is correct (+1 Alex). Please try changing your code to see whether it fixes the problem, and let us know what happens. If you don't want to change the type of your variables you could write `ReDim Preserve funcTable(0 To CLng(upsize) + CLng(ns))`

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the it was the database which had errors. I did not troubleshoot where exactly the error was but just took a backup before the updated one and it worked ok