# Write .exe in VB6 to Create Run-time error '6': Overflow

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I need to create an .exe that throws a VB run-time overflow error.  Does anyone have any VB6 code that could do this? I am trying to test a certain scenario for error handling.

Comment: See this question for an example of code that throws that error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351743/run-time-error-6visual-basic

Comment: "Too Localized"?  Ok.  I guess because its VB6.  Thanks everyone for the answers :)

Comment: "Too localized" was not a good choice (but was the "majority" voted reason to close).  However, it could have been legitimately closed as a duplicate of the link I posted.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  I'll keep a closer eye out for similar answers before duplicating q's in SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
Dim I As Integer

I = 32767 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Eric J.'s link (see above comment to question):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim upsize As Integer
  Dim ns As Integer
  Dim funcTable As Variant

  upsize = 34000
  upsize = 34000
  ReDim Preserve funcTable(0 To upsize + ns)

End Sub
```